# how to pass a value into a alert box created in a external php function file

Tags: javascript, php, alert

Hi as I asked in my previous question i would like to ask that is there a way in php where i can pass a value to a alert box which is created into a external function file ?? for eg. i created a function insmess() and the function simply creates an alert box which displays a message i was wondering that is it possible that if i pass the value like insmess($var). then the the value in the $var should come in the alert box. thanks in advance...
here is my code

```
function insmess(){

    print '<script type="text/javascript">';
    print 'alert("")';////this is where i want to show my value 
    PRINT '</script>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes...Use this:

```
'alert("'.$var.'");';
```

Full function would look like:

```
function insmess($var){

    print '<script type="text/javascript">';
    print 'alert("'.$var.'");';
    print '</script>';
}
```

Comment: yes it is..Just a bit modification was needed which i have done in my answer

Comment: hey thnks alot sir really this one helped me alot

Comment: done sir.. and how would i pass the value while calling the function??

Answer (score 2):

```
function insmess($var){
    print '<script type="text/javascript">';
    print 'alert("' . $var . '")';
    print '</script>';
}
insmess("mess");
```